# Firebase storage uploads file as 9b file

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

When I'm using the file method to upload files to firebase storage, Firebase is uploading them as a 9b files and the images are not loading, Also the progress gets logged as Nan though file upload using base64 string is working, Below is the code which is used when the file from the input picker changes

```
    const handleImageFileChange = async (e) => {
    try {
      const file = e.target.files ? e.target.files[0] : undefined;
      e.target.value = null;
      if (uploadTask) {
        uploadTask.cancel();
      }
      if (file) {
        const fileIsValid = validateFile(file);
        if (fileIsValid) {
          setState((prevState) => {
            return {
              ...prevState,
              uploadProgress: 0,
              uploading: true,
              imageUrl: URL.createObjectURL(file),
              imagePickerPopupVisible: false,
            };
          });

          const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

          const storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

          const fileName = `${Date.now()}_${file.name}`;

          console.log("File name ", fileName, file);

          uploadTask = storageRef
            .child(uid)
            .child("uploads")
            .child("note-images")
            .child(fileName)
            .put(file, "", {
              contentType: file.type ? file.type : "image/jpeg",
            });

          uploadTask.on(
            "state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
              var progress =
                (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
              console.log("progress", progress);
              progress =
                parseInt(progress) == 100
                  ? "100"
                  : parseInt(progress).toPrecision(2).toString();

              switch (snapshot.state) {
                case firebase.storage.TaskState.CANCELED: // or 'canceled'
                  setState((prevState) => {
                    return {
                      ...prevState,
                      uploading: false,
                      uploadProgress: 0,
                      imagePickerPopupVisible: false,
                    };
                  });
                  break;
                case firebase.storage.TaskState.PAUSED: // or 'paused'
                  setState((prevState) => {
                    return {
                      ...prevState,
                      uploading: false,
                      imagePickerPopupVisible: false,
                    };
                  });
                  break;
                case firebase.storage.TaskState.RUNNING: // or 'running'
                  setState((prevState) => {
                    return {
                      ...prevState,
                      uploading: true,
                      imagePickerPopupVisible: false,
                    };
                  });
                  break;
              }

              setState((prevState) => {
                return {
                  ...prevState,
                  uploadProgress: progress,
                };
              });
            },
            (error) => {},
            () => {
              uploadTask.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((downloadURL) => {
                const newElement = {
                  fileUrl: downloadURL,
                };

                console.log(downloadURL);

                Transforms.setNodes(editor, newElement, {
                  at: blockPath,
                });

                setState((prevState) => {
                  return {
                    ...prevState,
                    uploading: false,
                    uploadProgress: 0,
                    imageUrl: "",
                    fileInvalidError: false,
                    imagePickerPopupVisible: false,
                  };
                });
              });
            }
          );
        } else {
          setState((prevState) => {
            return {
              ...prevState,
              fileInvalidError: true,
              imagePickerPopupVisible: false,
            };
          });
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      setState((prevState) => {
        return {
          ...prevState,
          uploadProgress: 0,
          uploading: false,
          fileInvalidError: true,
          imagePickerPopupVisible: false,
        };
      });
    }
   };
```

Comment: You're uploading an empty string "" rather than the contents of the file.